# Unsupported Opperand Type Error

Tags: python, file, error-handling

(EDITED)
I am trying to make a piggybank by saving the previous money amounts to a file so you can access how much money you have previously had. But, it is giving me an error(see title). Please don't mark this as a duplicate because I already checked the others and they don't apple to my problem. Here is my code:

```
 def piggybank():
     newamount = 0.0
     file = open('piggybank.txt','r+')
     addedmoney = input('How much money are you adding?')
     file.write(addedmoney + '\n')
     for line in file:
         newamount += line
     print("You now have:\n", newamount)
```

Basically I am saying that the new amount is 0. Then I open my file in read and write mode and ask how much the user wants to add. Then I add it to a new line on my file and add up everything in the file. Lastly, I print the sum. However, this does not work because I keep getting the error. Please Help!

(I am sort of a noob at Python and Stack Overflow because I am 13 and just started learning.)

Here is my new code:

```
 def piggybank():
    file = open('piggybank.txt','r+')
    money = input('How much money are you adding?')
    file.write(money + '\n')
    for line in file:
        money += line
    print("You now have:\n", money)
    file.close()
```

If you look at my original code, I added a newline to money and I did that here as well. However, it adds the money strings as if they were strings so it gives '5.005.00' if you enter 5.00 twice. Does anyone know how to add a new line if you want to print numbers and not strings?

Comment: Does the error specify where the error occurs? (line number).

Answer (score 2):

It's because your line is string and newamount is number. That's why you get the error. You have to convert the string to number first before proceeding the math calculation.

```
def piggybank():
  newamount = 0.0
  file = open('piggybank.txt', 'r+')
  addedmoney = input('How much money are you adding?')
  file.write(str(addedmoney) + '\n')
  file.seek(0)
  for line in file:
    newamount += float(line)
  print("You now have:\n", newamount)
```

Comment: That didn't work but I changed the 0 to a string and it worked because line is a string apparently. But now there is a new error where it doesn't add the current one but the previous one so if I enter 3.50, it will give 0. Then if I enter 7.14, it will give 3.50. Lastly, if I give 5.10, it will give 10.64 and so on.

Comment: @PokeBros It is definitely best to keep newamount a floating point number since you are doing arithmetic, which you cannot do with a string. Have you confirmed that the contents of the file are correct in the first place? The newline might be causing issues, which is why just in case I added `strip()`. Also I suggest not writing to the file until you have calculated the total.

Comment: Another note is after writing the file cursor will be at the end of the file. Therefore, you should run file.seek(0) for the for loop to run from the beginning of the file. I edited the answer for you. Hope that helps

Comment: And I suggest to use 'a+' instead of 'r+' if you want to expanding the file.

Comment: I just changed my program and it works. But, I couldn't figure out how to start a new line to write more numbers so I had to use strings. Then it adds the numbers as if they're strings. For example, if you entered 5.00 twice it would give '5.005.00'. Does anybody know how to start a new line? The method I used in my code only works if you use a string for the money value. Here is my code:

Comment: def piggybank():
         file = open('piggybank.txt','r+')
         money = input('How much money are you adding?')
         file.write(money + '\n')
         for line in file:
             money += line
         print("You now have:\n", money)
         file.close()

Comment: You could change 'r+' to 'a+' and call the function as many time as you want to add more value to the file. Or you could use while loop to ask the user to input the number until he/she wants to stop (by inputting a special character e.g 'q' to quit).

Comment: Please don't use the comment section for extend debugging. Use [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def piggybank():
     newamount = 0.0 # newamount is a floating point number
     file = open('piggybank.txt','r+')
     addedmoney = input('How much money are you adding?')
     file.write(addedmoney + '\n')
     for line in file: # line is a string
         newamount += line # you are trying to add a floating point number to a string, so the error (I assume) happens here.
     print("You now have:\n", newamount)
```

In conclusion, the operands do not match. First you must convert the string to a floating point number like so:

```
newamount += float(line.strip()) # strip removes trailing whitespace
```

On another note, why write `addedmoney` to the file if you only need to store the total? You can try calculating newamount first and then proceed write that result.